# How do I recursively copy/download a whole webdav directory?

Tags: 11.04, nautilus, webdav

When I attempt to copy a folder from a webdav server to a local disk using Nautilus, it copies what appeas to be a manifest file (xml with the directory listing etc..). With cadaver I get an empty file.

I would like to be able to recursively copy a whole directory tree. Does anyone know how I can do this?

ps: I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 with Nautilus 2.32.2.1 and Cadaver 0.23.3

Comment: Do you need a tool with a GUI or is wget "good enough" for you?

Comment: I had a peek at wget, and it didn't claim to do webdav... It would work for me if it did

Comment: Try this: wget --user={username} --password={password}  --wait=20 --limit-rate=20K -r -p -U Mozilla http://{website}  If it works Ill add it as an answer ;)

Comment: But webdav is just plain https, so wget should work. a quick google search gave me http://www.astron.nl/northstar/nswiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?id=quickstarts%3Aconfigure_repository&cache=cache&media=quickstarts:webdav_manual.pdf to get a quick overview over wget with webdav

Comment: interesting.. when I point it to a webdav directory/collection, it grabs the html file for that directory (ie: with the list of things there as a webpage) then complains: "localhost/webdav/calibre-library: Not a directorylocalhost/webdav/calibre-library/index.html: Not a directory". When I point it at the webdav root, its rather random... ends up starting to download the whold webserver..
Note that it's https only and self-signed, so I had to add '--no-check-certificate'

Comment: @Ocaso: following those instructions I tried "wget -nH -np --cut-dirs=1 --user={uname} --password={pwd} --no-check-certificate --wait=1 -r  -U Mozilla https://my-host/my-webdav-dir/my-dir-in-webdav" ... not perfect (downloaded lots of 'index.html?C=M;O=D' and the like) but otherwise worked ok. Should be able to drop '--wait=1' I guess. Rinzwind: the '-np -nH' were handy.. One of you want to post an answer? (:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer summarises suggestions given in comments by @Ocaso and @Rinzwind.

I used this:

```
wget -r -nH -np --cut-dirs=1 --no-check-certificate -U Mozilla --user={uname} 
    --password={pwd} https://my-host/my-webdav-dir/my-dir-in-webdav
```

Not perfect (downloaded lots of 'index.html?C=M;O=D' and the like) but otherwise worked ok.

The "-r" downloads recursively, following links.

The "-np" prevents ascending to parent directories (else you download the whole website!).

The "-nH" prevents creating a directory called "my-host" (which I didn't want).

The "--cut-dirs=1" prevents creating a directory called "my-webdav-dir".

The "--no-check-certificate" is because I'm using a self-signed certificate on the webdav server (I'm also forcing https).

The "-U Mozilla" sets the user agent in the http request to "Mozilla" - my webdav server didn't actually need this, but I've included it anyway.

Comment: Using this to download a file from nextcloud it does download a file with the content: ```This is the WebDAV interface. It can only be accessed by WebDAV clients such as the Nextcloud desktop sync client.```. Any idea why that happens?

Comment: My guess is that nextcloud expects a user agent that looks like a WebDAV client (as opposed to Mozilla, which is a browser). If you have their client and a packet sniffer (eg: wireshark) you could find out what user agent it uses in it's requests.

Comment: Alternatively find out that it's user agent could  be "Mozilla/5.0 (Android) Nextcloud-android/3.8.0" from [the web](https://github.com/nextcloud/android/issues/4522).

Comment: Thank you very much drevicko!! I'll do this

Comment: Also [here](https://github.com/nextcloud/android/blob/master/src/main/res/values/setup.xml#L20). Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively you can mount it as a path to be accessed as part of your own file system.

```
sudo mount -t davfs https://your.remote/path /your/local/mount/point
```

Note: `/your/local/mount/point` has to be a real existing directory for this to work.

As far as I know you only need to run the following to get the command to work:
`sudo apt-get install davfs2` (If more configuration is required I apologise, it was a long time ago that I did this.)

(I added this as an answer because I feel Liam's answer didn't give enough info.)

Comment: using `sudo` to download a file doesn't really sound right.

Comment: @Equidamoid Mounting filesystems requires root access because it can allow you to bypass local UNIX permissions in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

I realize that this is an old question, but I was wanting to do this and I found [rclone](https://rclone.org) which is like rsync for the cloud and supports a lot of different protocols including WebDAV. You use `rclone config` to configure a remote and then just do `rclone copy remote:path .` and int will download everything. You can also use `rclone sync remote:path .` and it will do checking of the files and only copy updates. It is a golang program so it is very portable.

Answer (score 3):

Actually with Cadaver you can `cd` to directory from which you want to download files and `mget *`.

Comment: For this to be a useful answer, you need to tell the user how to do this.

Comment: Hm, `mget * .` in a folder or `mget foldername` results in `501 Not Implemented`. Did it really work for you on box.com?

Comment: @Wurstsalat You mustn't put  the extra '.'  ; also it takes filenames as arguments, so you will need to do `mget foldername/filename'.

Comment: That doesn't work for me when there's subdirectories (the _recursive_ part).

Answer (score 3):

You can use dav2fs to mount the webdav server, and then you can access it as you would a local directory.

Comment: also use this method, easy access to files and folders

Comment: And this method is the slowest in comparison with others and won't always work (bugs related to filename-squirks).