# How can I download all files from webdav page?

Tags: wget, webdav

My wget version is 1.16. I'm tried download video files from webdav page.

Command like this:

```
wget --http-user=user-id --http-password=password -nd -nH  "http://www.url.com/video/some/"
```

But I can downloaded only `index.html` file.
What is problem in my command?

Comment: give us the URL of this video

Comment: @Suncatcher It's same as this:
  http://tinymin.asuscomm.com/toby/

Comment: If index,html contains links to the other files, you can recursively download them with `wget -r`or `wget -m` (`man wget:  Recursive Retrieval Options`). See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104046/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to enclose links in quotes if it throws syntax errors, international characters are converted to unicode by default. **wget** accepts multiple arguments simultaneously.

Runnning **wget** *with quotes* over all three links from the comment was successfull, not to mention my wget is lower by version than yours, i.e. 1.15.

```
wget "http://tinymin.asuscomm.com/toby/some_file.mp4" "http://tinymin.asuscomm.com/toby/some_unresolvable_name.mp4" "http://tinymin.asuscomm.com/toby/even_more_scary_name.mp4"
```

**Note:** also, do not leave right slash at the end of the link as it directs wget to the wrong way (it treats those links as directories).

Comment: Thank you so much for you're answer. I'm already know way to download manually. You're answer need to run 3 times. I would to know download automatically just one command. Could I...? (and English is my mother's language. I'm apologize to you, if I did something mistake to you.)

Comment: @SuncheolKim, just send links as arguments and separate them by spaces. Edited the answer accordingly

Comment: You're answer is best way at this time. Thank you!!  :)