# Download Entire WebDav Directory

Tags: command-line, wget, webdav

Before asking this I saw [How do I recursively copy/download a whole webdav directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104046/how-do-i-recursively-copy-download-a-whole-webdav-directory) but it didn't answer my questions

When I run the command, it downloads robots.txt and the very first page. This page is just a directory listing of a folder called `cp`. Running `cat` against `cp`, I get HTML which links to sub-directories, but none of these have downloaded.

The links are relative i.e. `/dav/cp/folder` but in order for them to work, I *think* they have to be `/cp/folder`

Apologies if not making myself clear enough - happy to edit where necessary.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer that suggests to use wget on the page you mention does not use webdav and cannot do what ypu ask. Other answers mentionning davfs2 or dadaver are more correct answer, but still not complete, I think.

The key is to use webdav as a filesystem (ie a folder in the arborescence of your system). Then syncing 2 folders is as simple as `rsync -aHx /some/folder/. /another/folder/.`  The somewhat tricky part is to get the webdav resource mounted as a filesystem. Nautilus does not really cooperate with webdav by the way.

On a 16.04 system, launch a terminal app and type the following commands

```
sudo apt install davfs2
```

Be sure to answer yes when asked if unprivileged users should be allowed to mount WebDAV resources?

If davfs is already installed and you don't remember what you answered, just

```
 sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow davfs2
```

Then add all users that can use davfs to the davfs2 group. For example, to add yourself to the davfs2 group

```
sudo addgroup $USER davfs2
```

logout and login again. This is important as group membership is determined at login time.

Next, create a folder in your home (or somewhere else). To be sure not to use the folder without davfs, make sure the permissions are set to 0. When webdav is used, the permissions will be overridden.

```
mkdir -m 0 $HOME/remote
```

Next you need to add a line in the `/etc/fstab` file

```
echo "http://your.dav.server/path/to/resource $HOME/remote davfs noauto,user 0 0" |
  sudo tee -a /etc/fstab >/dev/null
```

You are now done with setup. Any time you need to use webdav, just type

```
mount ~/remote
```

remote content will then appear in the folder `~/remote`. You can use nautilus, unison, or command line tools to sync the davs folder with local folder.

Don't forget to use `umount ~/remote`when you are done. davfs2 uses some cache. It must be flushed properly.

Comment: This is a really helpful answer. For completeness' sake you may mention that the `mount` command may ask for a username/password if the Webdav server needs it.